# How to fix error node_modules react on typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, node-modules

I've tried to remove node_modules and reinstall it, but it doesn't work. The project was working fine until that the following error appear:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 4:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 35:11-43
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 12:17-41
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/destroy'
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 19:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 14:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 19:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 18:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
        - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 25:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 30:18-48 32:25-62 34:19-50
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/etag'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 25:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 30:18-48 32:25-62 34:19-50
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 28:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 18:11-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/express/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 25:10-30
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js 22:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 25:10-30
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 23:11-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
        - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 18:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/express/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js 26:11-28
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 19:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/mime'
 @ ./node_modules/send/index.js 31:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/send'
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 43:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/send'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 45:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 27:10-31
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js 1:0-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in '/home/juandav/react-app-store/my-store/node_modules/zlib/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js 20:11-26
 @ ./node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/raw.js 15:11-29
 @ ./node_modules/body-parser/index.js 138:15-41
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js 13:17-39
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js 10:0-41
 @ ./src/components/UserLogin.tsx 4:0-35 27:22-41
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-45 26:36-43
 @ ./src/index.tsx 5:0-24 14:35-38

ERROR in src/components/UserLogin.tsx
  Line 12:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions

src/components/UserSign_in.tsx
  Line 20:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

I am a bit lost here, so anyone has any clue to solve this problem ? Thanks in advance.
Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-store",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.26",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.14",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.24",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "bootswatch": "^5.1.3",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "modulename": "^0.0.4",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dotenv": "^0.1.3",
    "react-query": "^3.34.17",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "ts-dotenv": "^0.8.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "zlib": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "os": "^0.1.2",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-http": "^3.2.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "react-dotenv": {
    "whitelist": [
      "URLAPICART",
      "URLAPILOGIN",
      "URLAPIREGISTER"
    ]
  }
}
```

As seen from the above, I have installed the suggested packages from the errors (`crypto-browserify`, `stream-http`, `stream-browserify`,and `https-browserify`) and have included them in the `config-overrides.js` file. However, the errors still persist. This is the file `config-overrides.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
    module.exports = function override(config, env) {
        config.resolve.fallback = {
            url: require.resolve('url'),
            assert: require.resolve('assert'),
            crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
            http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
            https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
            os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
            buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
            stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        };
        config.plugins.push(
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                process: 'process/browser',
                Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
            }),
        );
    
        return config;
    }
```

How do I solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using react-script 5.0 + please use "react-scripts": "4.0.3", that issue is because of webpack config. They have removed the default poly-fill for Nodejs packages. [Read more about the current state here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756)

Comment: it didn't work, the error persist :(. Thanks anyways

Comment: use "react-scripts": "4.0.3" in your package.json

Comment: it worked! thank you very much, I've been searching a very long time.